# I cut my avocado roots too much

Tags: indoors, roots, cuttings, avocado

I have a 4year old avocado plant which is about 5 feet tall. Recently I cut the roots in attempt to thicken the stem, but I think I took way to much off and now it doesn't look too well. Stem is starting to scrump together, leaves slowly dried off following tips of the branches. One sad leaf is all that remains.
What can I do? Should I prune it down? Try with rooting hormones?
Have I just killed my plant or is it possible to save it?

Comment: It's hard to say with a tree, but for low annual heavy feeding plants, I'd keep them out of bright light and give them monopotassium phosphate or potassium sulfate.

Comment: Are you growing this in a  pot indoors or  in a pot outdoors?  Or in the ground?

Comment: In a pot indoors